# Question that needs no answer but has a good one

Tags: discussion, accepting, specific-question

At [position punctuation after a box](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233680/position-punctuation-after-a-box) I asked how to reformat punctuation that (as it turns out) is correct as is. There's an answer to my question as asked which I've upvoted. It doesn't seem quite right to accept it, but I don't want to leave the question without an accepted answer. Deleting the question destroys information someone might find useful some day.

Comment: Accepting an answer is up to you as the original poster. There's no requirement to accept anything.

Comment: you have the option to post (and accept) your own answer, saying as you say here that you've decided the correct thing to do is not do it.

Comment: I would **not** delete the question if there are (good) answers to it (although you think that no answer is needed). Users spend some time for providing an answer, so it's only to fair to let this answer alive. And if you don't completely disagree with an answer, it's no harm to accept it ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few choices:

1. Delete the post entirely;
2. Post a comment to the current answerer asking to amend their proposal to suit your needs;
3. Provide your own answer;
4. Post a bounty to solicit answers that may be more betterer... :)
5. Do nothing.

Here are the options based on the above choices:

1. You can't, since the answer has a positive score. See the FAQ [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/168244).
2. This is somewhat contained in the answer already, but not explicitly. Suggesting to be a little more explicit and include others' comments in such a statement might make the answer suit your needs more.
3. In some cases this is completely viable if your answer differs entirely from others. It may be awkward to grab that opportunity from someone else, but there's no guideline suggesting it can't/shouldn't be done. If you feel a self-answer will better-answer your own question, fill your boots.
4. In this case it may be a bit extreme, but it's still an option for the non-rep-hoarding-kind.
5. Another totally acceptable choice. An upvoted answer to a post removes it from the list of [unanswered questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/unanswered) (...the criteria there being "questions with no upvoted or [no] accepted answers").